# Spark Dataframe maximum on Several Columns of a Group

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

How can I get the maximum value for different (string and numerical) types of columns in a `DataFrame` in Scala using Spark?

Let say that is my data

```
+----+-----+-------+------+
|name|value1|value2|string|
+----+-----+-------+------+
|   A|    7|      9|   "a"|
|   A|    1|     10|  null|
|   B|    4|      4|   "b"|
|   B|    3|      6|  null|
+----+-----+-------+------+
```

and the desired outcome is:

```
+----+-----+-------+------+
|name|value1|value2|string|
+----+-----+-------+------+
|   A|    7|     10|   "a"|
|   B|    4|      6|   "b"|
+----+-----+-------+------+
```

Is there a function like in pandas with `apply(max,axis=0)` or do I have to write a UDF?

What I can do is a `df.groupBy("name").max("value1")` but I canot perform two `max` in a row neither does a `Sequence` work in `max()` function.

Any ideas to solve the problem quickly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this

```
df.groupBy("name").agg(max("value1"), max("value2"))
```

Comment: Is there also a way that I do not need to hardcode every column? Like a loop through all columns?
`for (col <- df.columns ){ df = df.groupBy("name").max(col) }` or something like that? Foor 30 columns that is cumbersome

Comment: Oh, and by the way: of course the string selection from colun string isn't considered in that solution.

Comment: A `max()` also does work on a string in `agg`. But it takes the max value in alphabetical order so one might consider to rename `null`.